# Unit testing a change in a function that is by design not reflected in the function return value

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def test():
    frm = "a@b.com"
    to = "c@d.com"
    # Original line: msg = MIMEText("Hello, Dear")
    msg = MIMEText("Hello, World")   # Changed line

    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
        s.sendmail(frm, to, msg.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        return False

    return True


test()
```

Now I want to unit test the change that I made on the msg line. In other words, I want to be able to assert that the msg value was indeed "Hello, World" when the code ran or that the sendmail() call indeed sent a message that said "Hello, World". How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using mocks. You don't want your unit test actually sending the email in any case.

Comment: I know but how to write a unit test specific to this use case was my question.